# The problem with translation of a SQL-query to Entity Framework

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-5.0

There are to tables Product and Price, the price table contains foreign key Price.ProductId to the Product table.
The Price table contains an info about prices for each products, these prices may be changed in accordance with StartDate, in other words an user can assign new price for any Product for exact StartDate.
How may it be implemented with help of Entity Framework? The Product entity model has a collection with entities from the Price table but it is not appropriate to extract so many Price entities because the Product has to be associated with only actual Price in the final query.

There are 2 models which map the tables -

```
public partial class Product
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Price> Prices { get; set; }
}

public partial class Price
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long ProductId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

It is impossible to extract full collection Product.Prices, only one actual Price must be associated to Product.
It looks like SQL-query below can extract data but how may it be done with help of EF?

```
select public.price., public.product. from public.product  
inner join public.price on public.price."ProductId" = public.product."Id"
where public.price."Id" in 
(
    select max(public.price."Id") from public.price
    where public.price."StartDate" <= current_date 
    group by  public.price."ProductId" 
)
```

Comment: *only one actual Price must be associated to Product* - you mean for any product you want to get the current price? Maybe you should have a PriceEnd column that is null for the current price, then put a property of CurrentPrice that does a Single or First with a predicate of priceend == null. It will be quicker to query than groupmaxing every price for every product every time

Answer (score 0):

Probably, it has to be similar like that -

```
var productsWithPrice = await db.Product
                        .Select(p => new 
                        { 
                            Product = p,
                            Price = p.Prices.Where(x => x.StartDate <= DateTime.UtcNow).OrderBy(x => x.StartDate).LastOrDefault()
                        })
                        .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the price terminating column (PriceEnd) mentioned by @CaiusJard we must presume the current price is the one with the latest Start Date. You can get this with the Not Exists predicate where there is no greater start date for the product price. This can be retrieved strictly from Prices table. Then join the result to the Products table. In straight SQL that becomes:

```
select prd.id, prd.productName, curr_pri.price
  from products prd
  join  (select productId, price
           from prices pri2
          where not exists (select null 
                              from prices pri3
                             where pri3.ProductId = pri2.ProductId  
                               and pri3.StartDate > pri2.StartDate
                           )  
       ) curr_pri
      on (prd.id = curr_pri.productId) ;
```

Unfortunately I will have to leave translation into your obscurification language (Entity Framework) as I do not know it. Hope this helps anyway.